# How do i remove hyphen which has a space on both sides in php

Tags: php

This is the string which has hyphen which i want to remove but it has space on both side

```
Year 7 Scheme of Learning – Lord of the Flies/Transactional Writing HAO
```

Comment: What do you want to as a result?  Why do you think having spaces either side makes it an issue to remove?

Comment: I'd try removing the hyphen as usual. And then removing duplicious spaces. In this way you also cover scenarios where 2 or more spaces precede or follow the hyphen.

Comment: This is not a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

I would use str_replace
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$string = "Year 7 Scheme of Learning – Lord of the Flies/Transactional Writing HAO";

// remove spaces and hyphen
$newString = str_replace(" - ","",$string);

// remove 1 space and hyphen
$newString = str_replace(" -","",$string);

// remove hyphen
$newString = str_replace("-","",$string);
```

Comment: Those 3 lines can be replaced with a single call (with the addition of a 4th condition of a space after the dash) ... `$newString = str_replace([' - ',' -','-','- '],'',$string);`.

Comment: Looks like the dash in the original is different to the dash in the replace examples.  You are trying to swap a hyphen for something like an en or em dash.  Copy the original character from the string into your search part argument of str_replace.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing your dash sandwiched between two spaces with a single space:

```
<?php
 
$string   = 'Year 7 Scheme of Learning – Lord of the Flies/Transactional Writing HAO';
$replaced = str_replace(' – ', ' ', $string);

var_dump($replaced);
```

Output:

```
string(69) "Year 7 Scheme of Learning Lord of the Flies/Transactional Writing HAO"
```